# Get minimum num recursively from a list

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to `lisp` and trying to write a recursive function that returns minimum number from a list. It also wants to detect atom. The following code returns error:

```
(defun minFromList (l)     
  (cond ((null l) nil) ; Causes error shown below
 ;  (cond ((null l) )   ; Causes the same error 
 ;  (cond ((null l) 0)  ; It causes always 0 to be the final return val.
        ((numberp l) l)
    ((numberp (car l)) (min (car l) (minFromList(cdr l))))
    ((listp (car l)) (min (minFromList (car l)) (minFromList (cdr l))))
    (t nil)       ; if all condition doesn't hold just return nil.
  )
)
```

Error:

```
*** - MIN: NIL is not a real number
```

Apparently the problem lies in where it returns nil/0 when the given list is null. What's possible workarounds? Thank you.

Environment) Ubuntu 11.10, clisp 2.49

---

Update) Although I already picked up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335746/577001) as the answer, I welcome if there are other ways especially w/o making new functions if any.

Here's the simplest code I made inspired by the chosen answer.

```
(defun minNum (a b)
  (cond ((null a) b)
    ((null b) a)
    (t (min a b)))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing two numbers, you need to deal with the `nil` case in some way.  This is easy to do.  Define your own version of `min` that satisfies

```
(min2 nil <x>)  =  <x>
(min2 <x> nil)  =  <x>
(min2 <x> <y>)  =  (min <x> <y>)   if <x>, <y> non-null
```

and use that.

Comment: I think you can use CLOS to achieve this style. What language is this anyways?

Comment: @claytontstanley What I posted isn't executable code, just a specification. :)  But yes, CLOS lets you specify `min2` in this way, though it would probably be overkill as compared to a `cond` in this case.  If you want pattern matching (unification, even) in CL, though, there's always the [CL-UNIFICATION](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-unification/) library, which works pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you get an error message because you try to use the result of your function as a number, and said result is `nil` when the function is called with an empty list as argument, so the evaluation that tries to use the result fails. This is not a Common Lisp problem - you have to decide what to return when the argument is empty. Maybe 0 is a good value, maybe some approximation of minus infinity - only you (or whoever uses your function) can tell.

As for getting the the minimum (or the sum or any other 'reduction') of a list, this is a pattern already handled by the [`reduce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm) Common Lisp standard function. So `min-from-list` could look something like:

```
CL-USER> (defun min-from-list (list &optional (default 0))
           (reduce #'min list :initial-value default))
MIN-FROM-LIST
CL-USER> (min-from-list '(1 2 -3))
-3
CL-USER> (min-from-list '(1 2 -3) -7)
-7
CL-USER> (min-from-list '())
0
CL-USER> (min-from-list '() -3)
-3
```

(the user can specify what the minimum of an empty list is - if none specified, it's 0).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I can think of is to wrap an application of `min`.

```
(defun min-or-nil (num-list) 
   (when num-list (apply #'min num-list)))
```